# Cannot find "Manage" folder while scaffolding identity pages in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, adminlte

**Environment**: Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.8.3, and ASP.NET Core.

When a user clicks the "Account Settings", the account setting page shall load at "content page" with keeping sidebar and header intact. But below code does not do so.

[image]

Below is the scaffolding folder structure

[image]

Below is the `cshtml` code for "Account Setting" link

```
 <li class="nav-header">Settings</li>
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a is-active-page asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" class="nav-link">
         <i class="nav-icon fas fa-cogs"></i>
          <p>
           Account Settings
          </p>
          </a>
      </li>
```

When I click the "Account settings" entire page refreshes and shows the below screen

[image]

BUT I would like to load "manage account" page in the "content page" . I mean sidebar and header shall show always. I understand this is something to do with `_Layout`.  However I am not able to find the **account->manage** folder or related pages for customization?

I understand these pages are hidden but where is it? How do I customize so that it fits at "content page" rather than full page view.

**Expectation**: When user clicks the "Account setting" , account details shall show as below.

[image]

Comment: we can add scaffold for the management view, it looks like you haven't added them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding scaffold for Manage views, we would get **account->manage** folder. Then we will have the views listed in our project, and we can custom the content to match your requirement.

> right click on the `Area folder -> add -> new scaffolded items... -> choose identity -> pick up the required views`

[image]

=============     Updated   ============

Loading the index page within "content" area requires us to modify the layout. I had a change like below within _Layout.cshtml.

```
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3" style="overflow:hidden">
        <div style="float:left;width: 200px;background: red;position: sticky;height: 80vh;">
            <div>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">direct to Privacy</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">direct to Index</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index">direct to account management</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style ="float:left;">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Added the scaffold  for Manage views but it still loads full screen, rather than loading inside "content area"

Comment: hmmm, then pls share the layout you defined in your project, because we don't have that side bar.. Per my understanding, in the default mvc project, we have the layout page which already define the area for loading all the views, so that if we requires the side bar,  it should be defined in the _Layout.cshtml file as well....

Comment: it worked after adding  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLTE/_Layout.cshtml"; at top of the index.cshtml of Manage folder.  Thank you